# How to set type of update "In App Update" when I update the app in google play console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, in-app-update

I can't find out where should I set the update type of "In App Update" feature in google play console.

Otherwise tell me how to use `AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE` and `AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**

**The Play Core API now supports checking for the priority of updates.** See https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#check-priority

---

I think you are misunderstanding the use of this feature. For each newer version available, you can update it in the app both ways.

"Flexible" means that the update will happen in the background and the user can continue using the app while the download happens and you get to let the user choose when to install it.

"Immediate" means that the update happens in the foreground, blocking the user to use the app while the download and install happens (to be used for critical updates).

You can learn more about this in this recent video of a talk at the Android Dev Summit 2019: https://youtu.be/_o_q6hatcIs

Comment: I think the OP meant where to set the priority when a new release is uploaded through Play developer console. But it looks like this can only be achieved through Play developer API https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks

Comment: @Pierre How to define that this new version is Immediate or flexible update ? How to set it from console ?

Comment: As pointed out by @hitmaneidos, this can be set using the Play Developer API. It is explained in the documentation that I linked to. See https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#update-priority